# Scaling after rotation changes the position of rect element

Tags: javascript, svg, transform

Original `rect`, with a rotation:
`<rect id="location_1" x="40" y="40" height="100" width="100" fill="red" stroke="2" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(45, 90, 90)"></rect>`

After scaling, the rotation center is changed based on the new `bbox`:
`<rect id="location_1" x="40" y="40" height="200" width="200" fill="red" stroke="2" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(45, 140, 140)"></rect>`

After scaling of the `rect`, if we update the rotation center then the postion of the `rect` is changed. But if we do not update the center then it works as expected, till the other transformations are applied.
***Scale as in updating width and height, not the scale transform***

My question is how to scale keeping the position of the element same.?

[**JSFiddle with the situation**](https://jsfiddle.net/u93q4oxd/)
If clicked on `Scale - No Update` the position is not changed but when clicked on `Scale - Update` the position changes.

```js
function scaleAndUpdate(id, update) {
  var
    elem = document.getElementById(id),
    bbox, cx, cy;
  elem.setAttribute('width', 200);
  elem.setAttribute('height', 200);
  if (update) {
    bbox = elem.getBBox();
    cx = bbox.x + (bbox.width / 2);
    cy = bbox.y + (bbox.height / 2);
    elem.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(45, ' + cx + ', ' + cy + ')');
  }
}

function reset(id) {
  var
    elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.setAttribute('x', 40);
  elem.setAttribute('y', 40);
  elem.setAttribute('width', 100);
  elem.setAttribute('height', 100);
  elem.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(45, 90, 90)');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="smallGrid" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5" />
      </pattern>
      <pattern id="grid" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#smallGrid)" />
        <path d="M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" style="pointer-events: none;"></rect>
    <g id="locationGroup">
      <rect id="location_1" x="40" y="40" height="100" width="100" fill="red" stroke="2" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(45, 90, 90)"></rect>
      <circle cx="90" cy="20" r="5" fill="black"></circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <button onclick="scaleAndUpdate('location_1')">Scale - No Update</button>
  <button onclick="scaleAndUpdate('location_1', true)">Scale - Update</button>
  <button onclick="reset('location_1')">Reset</button>
</div>
```